# Android Flutter TCP

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sockets

I am attempting to build an app for use at my house, just turns on and off lights on my outside patio.  Most of the work is straight forward and it is almost working well enough to use it.  The server is a ESP32 microcontroller.  The question is, if the controller looses power for some reason, how can it be detected in the flutter app.

I send a pulse message every minutes, I was hoping the dart socket would time out and emit an error in the listener.  The listener is implemented as:

```
_socketSubscription = socket!.asBroadcastStream().listen((event) {
    String s = String.fromCharCodes(event);
    add(Received(
      message: Message(
        message: String.fromCharCodes(event),
        timestamp: DateTime.now(),
        sender: Sender.Server,
      )));
  },
  onDone: () {
    log("Done:");
  },
  onError: (error) {
    log('error $error');
  },
);
```

and when I unplug the microcontroller onDone or onError are never called.

I thought I could check the length of the socket, how much data is accumulating, and I get an exception that the stream already being listened to.

I am not trying to sell this app, it is just a learning exercise, I will use the app so it is a useful exercise.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of socket it this? TCP? UDP?

Comment: A tcp socket.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Dart but I assume it works similar to socket interfaces in other languages.

If you close a TCP connection correctly, a message is sent to the other side that the connection is going to be closed. This is then acknowledged by the other side. If you unplug the microcontroller, this message is not sent and so the other side (your app) does not know that the connection is gone. This is probably the reason `onDone` is not called.

If you do not send data over a TCP connection, no data goes over the network. When no data goes over the network, nothing can go wrong. If you unplug the microcontroller, it no longer sends data and won't be any errors on the TCP level. This is probably the reason `onError` is not called.

There are two common solutions to this problem:

- Use a time-out. If you know the microcontroller sends a message every minute and you do not receive a message each minute, you know the connection is gone.0
- Ask the controller if it is still connected. Send a message to the microcontroller for which the microcontroller will send a reply. If you do not get a reply, you know the connection is gone.